# How to select unique values in MySQL and order by another field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with the following columns and rows

```
sender      receiver   timestamp
1           176        305
176         1          503
1           116        2011
45          1          106
1           176        309
```

Okay. So far so good. The thing is, that I would love to display all of the data once and order it by timestamp, so I would get something like this:

```
sender/receiver      timestamp
116                  2011
176                  503
45                   109
```

This means that I will only get the highest value of timestamp even though the sender/receiver occur more then once.

I really hope you understand my question.

Comment: Where's sender/receiver 1 in your output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN Sender = 1 THEN Receiver ELSE Sender END `sender/receiver`,
        MAX(timestamp) time_stamp
FROM    tableName
WHERE   1 IN (Sender, Receiver)
GROUP   BY CASE WHEN Sender = 1 THEN Receiver ELSE Sender END
ORDER   BY time_stamp DESC
```

The `CASE` statement takes the value of the `Receiver` is the `Sender = 1` otherwise `Sender`. The use of `MAX()` takes the greatest value of timestamp.

Comment: why we need  WHERE   1 IN (Sender, Receiver)..if we always have 1 in either in sender or receiver?

Comment: @Peeyush you don't need `WHERE` if you have always 1 in either in sender or receiver. But before the question has been edited. The OP tells that he wants to filter records where `1` exists in either of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
SELECT sender_receiver
     , Max(timestamp) As max_timestamp
FROM   (
        SELECT sender As sender_receiver
             , timestamp
        FROM   your_table
        WHERE  sender <> 1

        UNION ALL

        SELECT receiver As sender_receiver
             , timestamp
        FROM   your_table
        WHERE  receiver <> 1
       ) As x
ORDER
    BY max_timestamp
```